# How to capture variable from nginx location having not operator

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Here is the location where URL not having words welcome and home is selected.

```
location ~* "^\/(?!\b(welcome|home)\b)[^\/\.]*$" {
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
    proxy_set_header Host $host ;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/custom-pages/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I want to pass the slug in $1 variable.

Comment: What part does `$1` represent? You need to place parentheses around the part you wish to capture. If it's the entire URI, use `$uri`.

Comment: Thanks, Richard `$uri` worked. I have replaced `$1` by `$uri`. I thought $1 would capture the first variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$uri` to get the complete url as already suggested by **@Richard**, but in case you have a little more complex location, something like `/my-directory/<<slug>>`, then `$uri` won't serve your purpose.

For such cases, you can easily use a capture group as `([^\/\.]*)` and get it in `$2`:

```
location ~* "^\/my-directory\/(?!\b(welcome|home)\b)([^\/\.]*)$" {
    ...

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/custom-pages/$2$is_args$args;

    ...
}
```

Also, your negative lookahead `(?!\b(welcome|home)\b)` will discard all the locations that start with **welcome** or **home**, like `/welcome-here` or `/home-is-where-u-r`.

So, to be able to capture those and discard only `/home` and `/welcome`, you can simply change it to `(?!(welcome|home)$)`